# Athena returns empty results from Firehose > Glue > S3 parquet setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have set up a Kinesis Firehose that passes data through glue which compresses to and transforms JSON to parquet and stores it in an S3 bucket. The transformation is successful and I can query the output file normally with apacheDrill. I cannot however get Athena to function. Doing a preview table (select * from s3data limit 10) I get results with the proper headers for the columns but the data is empty.

**Steps I have taken:**

- I already added the newline to my source: `JSON.stringify(event) + '\n';`
- Downloaded the parquet and queried successfully with apacheDrill
- Glue puts the parquet file in YY/MM/DD/HH folders. I have tried moving the parquet to the root folder and I get the same empty results.

**The end goal is to get data eventaully into Quicksights**, so if I'm going about this wrong let me know.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hello Corada! Could you explain how you created the Athena table and how your data is disposed in the S3 bucket (path the files)?

Comment: I manually created an AWS glue table that exactly matches the fields in the JSON sent to firehose (I originally had a partition on a timestamp field which caused "zero record returned", now I have no partitions... baby steps). The data is disposed by Glue into the s3 bucket (no encryption, snappy compression is enforced by the parquet conversion i think?). Glue default places the files into YY/MM/DD/HH folders.


In athena I loaded the table from the glue definition (drop down is automatically there).

Comment: Hi Corada, Can you try one more thing? Create a glue Crawler to crawl to the directory and see the table definition generated by glue and whether glue was able to detect the schema correctly. Then try to do a select from the glue catalog table. Please let me know your findings.